# While loop in R programming

Tags: r

Kindly help me understand how the value of speed changes in the following code.
Can someone help me understand why the value of speed is reduced 42 and eventually at 36. Thanks in advance.

```
speed <- 64

while (speed > 30) {
  print(paste("Your speed is",speed))
  if ( speed > 48 ) {
    print("Slow down big time!")
    speed <- speed -11
    print(speed)
  } else {
    print("Slow down!")
    speed <- speed -6

  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is a good practice to provide a reason if you downvote. I this case for instance, it is not obvious to me why this question should be downvoted.

Comment: to try and find out by yourself, you could put your code in a function (with `speed` as parameter) and then use `debug` to follow speed value step by step

Answer (score 2):

Loop 1: value of `speed` is 64, so `if` statement is executed, reducing speed by 11 --> 53

Loop 2: value of `speed` is 53, so `if` statement is executed, reducing speed by 11 --> 42

Loop 3: value of `speed` is now 42, which is less than 48, so `else` is executed, bringing speed down by 6 --> 36